# Read binary file with TPL

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, binaryfiles

I want read binary file with task parallel library. But I get this error

```
"The process cannot access the file 'D:\Binary.bin' because it is 
 being used by another process."
```

My code segment is here:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
       new ReaderWriterBinaryFile().ReadWriteFile();
    }
}

public class ReaderWriterBinaryFile
{
    public void ReadWriteFile()
    {
      //  WriteBinaryFile();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                  {
                                      var fs1 = new FileStream(@"D:\Binary.bin", FileMode.Open);
                                      var br = new BinaryReader(fs1);
                                      ReadBinaryFile(fs1, br, 1);
                                  });

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var fs1 = new FileStream(@"D:\Binary.bin", FileMode.Open);
            var br = new BinaryReader(fs1);
            ReadBinaryFile(fs1, br, 2);
        });



        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private void WriteBinaryFile()
    {
        var fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Binary.bin", FileMode.Create);
        var bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);

        WriteBinaryFile(fs, bw);
    }

    private void ReadBinaryFile(FileStream fs, BinaryReader br, int taskNo)
    {

        var readBytes = br.ReadBytes(4000000);

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i += 4)
        {
            var intValue = BitConverter.ToSingle(readBytes, i);
            Console.WriteLine(taskNo+"  ----       "+intValue);
        }


        fs.Close();
        br.Close();
    }

    private void WriteBinaryFile(FileStream fs, BinaryWriter bw)
    {
        for (int i = 22; i < 100000000; i++)
        {
            var age = Convert.ToSingle(i);
            bw.Write(age);   
        }

        fs.Close();
        bw.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("-------write end....");
    }`
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1GtC.png)

Comment: You're reading `@"D:\Binary.bin"` in two places. That's your problem.

Comment: thanks @Enigmativity, for your quick reply. how to read the file with TPL so that I can read and get value faster.

Comment: Why use TPL? It'll just slow it down if you read the file twice. Just read it once. Can you explain why you're trying to read it twice?

Comment: thnks. I am working in a project of my own where a large binary file consists date time wise 10 variables data. For eg, 10 years result data of binary file which has each day and each hour wise data of 10 variables. 10/6/2016 to 10/6/2026 years data. In UI, user choose start and end date with variables, then I show data in a table(2 columns, time column and value column) from binary file. When user's date range contains 1 million dates, then it takes many times to read. If I can create 3/4 tasks with TPL and read 500k each date data of each task then it may better. U can give better solution.

Comment: Reading from a disk is usually limited by the speed of the disk. Trying to do it in parallel from more than one thread won't help you, it's actually likely to hurt you, because the disk now has to go back and forth.

Comment: @Monir - svick is absolutely right. Multiple threads only really helps CPU-bound operations. Disk-based activities are usually faster when performed as a serial operation.